# vb.net: Why does Email-form return the ID of the value in a dropdown list as oppose to the text

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a form written in vb.net. Upon clicking the submit button, the information in the form is emailed over to a specific email address. The form successfully captures the information from my text-box controls, but for the Dropdownlist controls, it brings back the ID of the list-item as oppose to the text.

Hypertext:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCarrier" runat="server" DataTextField="Carrier_Name" 
                            DataValueField="Carrier_ID">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

The original developer has it set to where the list-items are bind to the dropdown-list via the following code snippet, which uses a global variable: "dl" to access another function stored in a dataLayer file:

```
Dim dl As New DataLayer

Me.ddlCarrier.DataSource = dl.GetCarriers
        Me.ddlCarrier.DataBind()
        Me.ddlCarrier.DataTextField = "carrier_name"
        Me.ddlCarrier.DataValueField = "carrier_id"
```

...Function that is stored in the dataLayer file:

```
Public Function GetCarriers() As DataTable
        Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ShipperNotificationConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim myCommand As SqlDataAdapter

        myCommand = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT carrier_id,carrier_code,carrier_name,active from Carrier", connectionString)

        Dim dtCarriers As DataTable = New DataTable()
        myCommand.Fill(dtCarriers)
        Return dtCarriers
    End Function
```

lastly, the code snippet used the in the email function:

```
"<tr><td><b>Carrier:</b>" + ddlCarrier.SelectedValue.ToString() + "</td></tr>" & _
```

...The dropdownlist successfully populates the text, but when submitted via the form, I get the ID instead of the text itself. Could I get some help as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ddlCarrier.SelectedValue` try `ddlCarrier.SelectedItem.Text`

Comment: Thanks, I was getting close; at first I tried ddlCarrier.SelectedItem.Text but obtain the same results, but ddlCarrier.SelectedItem.Text worked! Thanks again, I greatly appreciated it.

Comment: sorry, I meant to say: "At first, I tried ddlCarrier.SelectedItem.ToString, but obtain the same results, but ddlCarrier.SelectedItem.Text worked!" however, thanks again!!

Comment: Yes I figured that :) Glad it the solution was helpful!